# How to implement modern Card component (a'la Material Design 3.0) in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, material-design, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, material-you

How can I implement using Compose these modern, subtle Card components, seen in updated Google apps?

[image]

They don't have border, they are a little bit elevated, with a subtle shadow behind. I tried fiddling with modifiers on standard Card, but didn't come close to this result.

Similar versions of them (elevated `Filled`?) appear on [Material Design 3.0 docs](https://m3.material.io/components/cards/overview), but its implementation is not yet available for Compose.

Comment: You can use this https://gist.github.com/cedrickring/0497965b0658d6727aaec531f59e8c5c to implement coloured shadows to the cards

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see much differences with previous card. Maybe the border radius and the elevation are higher. In the image you posted looks like they are using a background color similar to the shadow color to reduce contrast.

Anyway here you can find the new Material Design 3 for Compose: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3

Answer (score 0):

If you want a complete tutorial, follow [this Material 3 Card article](https://semicolonspace.com/jetpack-compose-material3-card/).

The Material 3 card is similar to Material 2.

Example:

```
Card(
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 16.dp),
    border = BorderStroke(width = 2.dp, color = Color.Green)
) {
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 16.dp),
        text = "SemicolonSpace",
        fontSize = 22.sp
    )
}
```

Output:

[image]